# GoogleApiClient dentro de recycleViewAdapter?

Tags: java, api, android-recyclerview

O `app` tem um fragmento com um `recyclerview` e um `FAB`. Ao clicar no `FAB`, abre um dialogo onde o usuário informa endereços, entre outras informações.

Os campos de entrada de endereço são do tipo AutoCompleteTextView e recebem sugestões de endereços a medida que o usuário entre com a informação.

Isso foi feito usando `GoogleApiClient` com `GEO_DATA_API`, conforme o codigo a seguir:

```
public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment
        implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerFragment";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RunDbHelper runDbHelper;
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private OnOkButtonListener mCallback;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;

    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;

    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));
    private static LatLngBounds BOUNDS_AUTOCOMPLETE;

    public RecyclerFragment() {
        this.mCallback = null;
    }

    public void setAutocompleteBounds(LatLng centerLatLng){
        if (centerLatLng!= null && !centerLatLng.toString().isEmpty()){
            Double latSW, lngSW, lngNE, latNE;
            latSW = centerLatLng.latitude-.5;
            lngSW = centerLatLng.latitude-.5;
            lngNE = centerLatLng.latitude+.5;
            latNE = centerLatLng.latitude+.5;
            BOUNDS_AUTOCOMPLETE = new LatLngBounds(
                    new LatLng(latSW, lngSW), new LatLng(latNE, lngNE));
        } else {
            BOUNDS_AUTOCOMPLETE = new LatLngBounds(
                    new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                    .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                    .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .build();
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: " + e);
        }

        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_AUTOCOMPLETE, null);

        runDbHelper = RunDbHelper.getInstance(getContext());
        List<RunData> mList = runDbHelper.getAllRuns();
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mList);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvRunList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Data entry dialog to add runs
                dialogInsertRun();
            }
        });     
        return view;
    }

    public void dialogInsertRun() {

        // Get the Activity for layout inflater as this dialog runs inside a fragment
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_run, null);

        // Dialog Builder
        AlertDialog.Builder addRunDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        addRunDialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_insert_run_title)
                .setView(view);

        // Data entry field objects
        final AutoCompleteTextView collectAddressACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actv_new_collect_address);
        final EditText collectPersonEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.new_collect_person);

        collectAddressACTV.setThreshold(3);
        collectAddressACTV.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        collectAddressACTV.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);

        addRunDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                RunData runData = new RunData();
                runData.collect_person = getStringOrEmpty(collectPersonEditText);
                runData.collect_address = getStringOrEmpty(collectAddressACTV);

                if (!(runData.collect_address.isEmpty() && runData.delivery_address.isEmpty())) {

                    runData = runDbHelper.insertRun(runData, getActivity());
                    if (runData != null) {                          
                        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), runDbHelper.getAllRuns());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                        mCallback.addMarkersToMap(runData);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.dialog_insert_run_toast_nowhere, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        addRunDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        addRunDialog.create();
        addRunDialog.show();
    }

    private String getStringOrEmpty(EditText editText) {
        String mString = editText.getText().toString();
        mString = (mString == null || mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString);
        return mString;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(TAG, "Google Places API connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }   

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.

        }
    };
}
```

Depois de inserir as informações, elas vão pro banco de dados e pro recyclerview, formando uma lista de cardviews.

Cada cardview tem um botão de edição. Ao tocar um botão, abre-se um dialogo com o form. de edição. Nesta hora, eu gostaria de usar o mesmo recurso de sugestão de endereços.

Toda a parte de edição está pronta. Falta apenas este GoogleApiClient funcionar...

O codigo do adaptador do recyclerview é este:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>
        implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private static String mCollect, mDelivery, mRunEnded, mUnknownDestiny, mIndeterminate;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;

    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 1;
    private Context context;
    private List<RunData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private RunDbHelper runDbHelper;

    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));
    private static LatLngBounds BOUNDS_AUTOCOMPLETE;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<RunData> dataList1) {

        mCollect = context.getString(R.string.str_collect).trim();
        mDelivery = context.getString(R.string.str_delivery).trim();
        mIndeterminate = context.getString(R.string.str_indeterminate);
        mRunEnded = context.getString(R.string.this_run_ended);
        mUnknownDestiny = context.getString(R.string.unknown_destiny);

        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList1;
        this.runDbHelper = RunDbHelper.getInstance(this.context);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_row, parent, false);
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                    .enableAutoManage(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this) // nada do que tentei colocar aqui no lugar do XXXXXXX funcionou!
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .build();
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: " + e);
        }

        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_AUTOCOMPLETE, null);

        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }


    // Parse data from dataList to holder and setup all Views
    // Here is part of the magic
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        // holding regular views
        holder.runID.setText(dataList.get(position).run_id);

        holder.collectPerson.setText(dataList.get(position).collect_person);
        holder.collectAddress.setText(dataList.get(position).collect_address);

        // this booleans help set some views on/off accordingly
        Boolean collected = dataList.get(position).parcel_collected.equals("1");
        Boolean collectAddressIsEmpty = dataList.get(position).collect_address.isEmpty();

        holder.ivEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RunData runData = new RunData();
                runData.run_id = holder.runID.getText().toString();              
                runData.collect_person = holder.collectPerson.getText().toString();
                runData.collect_address = holder.collectAddress.getText().toString();       
                dialogEditRun(runData, position);
            }
        });    
    }

    String makeSureLatLng(String lat, String lng) {
        return (lat == null || lng == null || lat.isEmpty() || lng.isEmpty() ? null : lat + "," + lng);
    }

    boolean isUsable(TextView textView) {
        return (!(textView == null || textView.getText().toString().isEmpty()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public void dialogEditRun(RunData runData, int position) {

        // Get the Activity for layout inflater as this dialog runs inside a fragment
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View inflaterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_run, null);
        // Data entry field objects
        final String mRunID;

        final AutoCompleteTextView collectAddressACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.actv_edit_collect_address);
        final EditText collectPersonEditText = (EditText) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.edit_collect_person);
        final TextView parcel_collected = (TextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.editDelivered);         

        mRunID = runData.run_id;        

        parcel_collected.setText(runData.parcel_collected);
        collectAddressACTV.setText(runData.collect_address);
        collectPersonEditText.setText(runData.collect_person);


        // Set directions into recyclerViewAdapter for autocomplete
        collectAddressACTV.setThreshold(3);
        collectAddressACTV.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        collectAddressACTV.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);

        // Dialog Builder
        AlertDialog.Builder editRunDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        editRunDialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_update_run_title).setView(inflaterView);
        editRunDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                RunData runData = new RunData();

                int position = (int) run_date.getTag();
                runData.run_id = mRunID; 
                runData.collect_person = getStringOrEmpty(collectPersonEditText);
                runData.collect_address = getStringOrEmpty(collectAddressACTV);                              

                if (!runData.collect_address.isEmpty() ){
                    // try to update, if success update recycler.
                    if (runDbHelper.updateRun(runData, context)){

                        // atualiza o recyclerview
                        dataList.remove(position);
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        dataList.add(position,runData);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, dataList.size());
                        notifyItemInserted(position);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Not updated record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.dialog_insert_run_toast_nowhere, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

        editRunDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        editRunDialog.create();
        editRunDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(TAG, "Google Places API connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(context,
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView runID, collectPerson, collectAddress;
        TextView collectLat, collectLng;
        ImageView ivEdit;
        SwitchCompat swcCollect;

        RecyclerViewHolder(View rowView) {
            super(rowView);
            runID = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.runId);                
            ivEdit = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivEdit);
            collectPerson = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.collectPerson);
            collectAddress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.collectAddress);
        }
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
        }
    };
}
```

Tentei seguir o modelo do `RecyclerFragment`, mas tem algo errado e não consigo instanciar o `GoogleApiClient` no método `onCreateView`.

Note que estava usando Google Places WebService e com esta API funciona, mas ela não deve ser usada no `app` em produção, por isso estou mudando para Google Places API for Android.

Tomara, possa me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar, inclusive no SOEN achei a resposta na documentação. Como não houve nenhuma tentativa de responder e nem sequer um comentário, acho que vou relatar o que encontrei porque deu certo e você pode se encontrar em situação semelhante.

O problema está nesta parte:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
```

Especificamente, nesta método:

```
.enableAutoManage(getActivity(), GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
```

Enquanto ele facilita o gerenciamento do ciclo de vida deste cliente de API, assim como o Highlander, só pode haver um e por isso não poderia usar a segunda vez.

A solução foi usar esta variação:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

Além disso, é preciso conectar e desconectar o cliente. Isso é feito chamando os métodos `connect()` e `disconnect()` nos locais apropriados e nos eventos `onCreate()` e `onDestroy()` da atividade ou do fragmento.